How to start a Kotlin Flow but delay the result it returns by a certain amount of time if it completes early
I'm trying to create a Flow that "modifies" the current Flow by waiting at least a certain amount of time before returning the first result.
I'd like, of course, to start processing the current Flow right away but to "withhold" the result until that time is passed.
I need this on an Android app I'm currently writing because if things are loading fast enough, the Flow would complete during the NavHost enter transition, causing stutter.
Of course, the alternative would be to start the request (not a HTTP one, sorry) right away and waiting for the transition to end, but I'm afraid the solution would be similar to this one (except for the "waiting" Flow to be different than a delay).
I found out about the zip flow because it says:

Zips values from the current flow (this) with other flow using provided transform function applied to each pair of values. The resulting flow completes as soon as one of the flows completes and cancel is called on the remaining flow.

And the example they give is:
val flow = flowOf(1, 2, 3).onEach { delay(10) }
val flow2 = flowOf("a", "b", "c", "d").onEach { delay(15) }
flow.zip(flow2) { i, s -> i.toString() + s }.collect {
    println(it) // Will print "1a 2b 3c"
}

In the example, the remaining "d" item is discarded.
The last phrase is what I'm seeing happening in my code.
The "waiting" flow isn't getting cancelled automatically when zip is done.
Since I also restart this Flow on Pull-to-refresh, the next time it gets stuck (doesn't happen without this delayResultByAtLeast).
This is my code and from LogCat, I can only see:

START
DELAY: L: 252

but I can't see "END"...
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.zip
import kotlin.time.Duration

/**
 * Waits [d] to produce a result if the result of the current flow is ready before [d].
 * For example, if [d] is 5 seconds and the result of the current flow is ready at `t = 2 seconds`,
 * this "modifier" will wait another 3 seconds before returning the result.
 *
 * If, instead, the result is ready at `t = 7 seconds`, return it when it's ready.
 *
 * @param d the minimum time to wait for the result.
 */
fun <T> Flow<T>.delayResultByAtLeast(d: Duration): Flow<T> {
    val waitFlows = flow {
        val ctx = currentCoroutineContext()

        Log.d("FLOW", "START")
        val start = System.currentTimeMillis()

        delay(d)

        val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val delta = end - start
        Log.d("FLOW", "DELAY: L: $delta")

        while(ctx.isActive) {
            emit(Unit)
        }

        Log.d("FLOW", "END")
    }

    return this.zip(waitFlows) { a, _ -> a }
}

Is there a way to automatically cancel the other Flow when the first one completes?
Or is the approach totally wrong? (BTW, it may be because it's the first time I'm using Kotlin Flow and Jetpack Compose).
EDIT: The Flow is running on another context (via newSingleThreadContext).

Zip is not a good solution here. Issue with it is it combines values from each flow only once before sending them, so even if it worked correctly your "delay flow" ends up being very awkward as it needs to emit as many "dummy" values as your desired flow does.
If I understand correctly you can just get by with a simple delay right before your first value is emitted.
Try this:
fun <T> Flow<T>.delayResultAtLeast(d: Duration) = flow {
    var deadline = System.currentTimeMillis() + d.inWholeMilliseconds;

    emitAll(
        (this@delayResultAtLeast).transform {
            if (deadline > 0) {
                delay(System.currentTimeMillis() - deadline)
                deadline = 0L
            }
            emit(it)
        }
    )
}


The thing is, I'd like the current Flow to start executing right away (eg. it may be a network request and it takes 2 seconds to complete). I believe I need to transform the flow from cold to hot but I don't know the best way to do it.
The delay must not stall the current flow. If I call it with a delay of 3 seconds (exaggerating) and the network request takes 2 seconds, I should get the result after only 3 seconds. Viceversa, delay=3 seconds, network=5 seconds, I should get the result after 5 seconds.

UPDATE: I changed the function name to better reflect the intent (now it's delayResultByAtLeast)

This transformation does not delay collection of upstream flow. Maybe you should clarify how your web request is declared and collected.

I managed to make it work somehow (please check my answer). It works even though probably it isn't the best code... Thanks, anyway.

I've managed to make it work by changing delayResultByAtLeast to a suspend function and passing a scope (created with rememberCoroutineScope on the Compose-side). Then I launch the job with async and I launch the delay in the same way. I, then, await them all and return the collected result.
On the Compose-side, I then use the returned result to update a MutableState<T> (created with remember { mutableStateOf(...) }) so that it recomposes the screen.
NOTE: surely, some error- and cancellation- handling code is missing.
This is the LogCat:
FLOW  org.example.Foo  D  START
JOB   org.example.Foo  D  JOB RESULT
FLOW  org.example.Foo  D  DELAY: L = 252
FLOW  org.example.Foo  D  END
FLOW  org.example.Foo  D  COMPLETE: null

This is the updated code:
suspend fun <T> Flow<T>.delayResultByAtLeast(
    d: Duration,
    scope: CoroutineScope,
): T {
    var res: T? = null

    val a1 = scope.async { this@delayResultByAtLeast.collect { res = it } }

    if(d.isPositive()) {
        val waitFlows = flow {
            Log.d("FLOW", "START")
            val start = System.currentTimeMillis()

            delay(d)

            val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val delta = end - start
            Log.d("FLOW", "DELAY: L: $delta")

            emit(Unit)

            Log.d("FLOW", "END")
        }.onCompletion { c ->
            Log.d("FLOW", "COMPLETE: " + c?.message)
        }

        val a2 = scope.async { waitFlows.collect {} }

        listOf(a1, a2).awaitAll()
    } else {
        a1.await()
    }

    return res!!
}


This entire approach is a mess. You feed a custom scope into a function (bad style). You create "waitFlows" that only causes a fixed delay to emit 1 dummy value (since now this function is not a flow, calculating delta is pointless). Source flow has really weird constraint: it must end aka using this function on shared flow will never return. Source flow is internally collected on different scope than suspend function is running on - a violation. I assume you're propagating bad decisions from your ViewModel layer that you haven't posted.

I will probably rethink the code, but I wanted to try a generic way to launch two jobs on (possibly) different threads (even just the main thread and another thread) and await the results of both. All of this launched from Compose. And the result used in a Composable.
Of course (if I understood well) everything inside a single CoroutineScope so that they're cancelled together...
Is this a mess? It seems a pretty basic task to me...

You don't need a "different thread" for a delay or await(), that's the basic benefit of coroutines. Suspending functions should run in the scope they are called on, maybe switch dispatcher using withContext{} internally but feeding them scope to use is unhealthy. BTW if you only need first result from "web request flow" this entire function could be replaced with:  suspend fun <T> Flow<T>.delayResultByAtLeast(d: Duration) = coroutineScope { launch { delay(d) } ; first() }.
